# C# Equivalent of JScript's new ActiveXObject

Tags: c#, activex, jscript.net

I am trying to use the functionality of new `ActiveXObject()` found in JScript.NET in C#. How can I do this?

And don't say that anything you can do with COM objects can be done in C#. If I wanted to do it that way, I already would have.

Comment: I think you simply have to reference the COM dll in the Add Reference dialog, and Visual Studio will create a Wrapper for you. in the wrapper, you'll find a class you can instantiate.

Comment: Any way to do this just using Notepad? I know I shouldn't but I do.

Comment: There's so much plumbing that I would highly suggest to use VS. Even if you switch to one of the free version (maybe SharpDevelop or Mono develop can help?)

Comment: Ok. I will consider that. Then is it possible without VS?

Comment: With .Net SDK maybe, and the [`tlbimp.exe` command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx.aspx)

Comment: So there is no way to do this purely in the C# code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create instances of COM objects using

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(ProgID))
```

and then work with them using late binding. For example:

```
using System.Reflection;
...

Type wshType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WScript.Shell");
object wshShell = Activator.CreateInstance(wshType);
wshType.InvokeMember("Popup", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, wshShell, new object[] {"Hello, world!"});
```

or, using C# 4's `dynamic` keyword:

```
// NB: Add reference to Microsoft.CSharp.dll
dynamic wshShell = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WScript.Shell"));
wshShell.Popup("Hello, world!");
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for.